# Select last row from each column of multi-index Pandas DataFrame based on time, when columns are unequal length

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, multi-index

I have the following Pandas multi-index DataFrame with the top level index being a group ID and the second level index being `when`, in ISO 8601 time format (shown here without the time):

```
                                     value      weight
                         when                     
5e33c4bb4265514aab106a1a 2011-05-12   1.34       0.79
                         2011-05-07   1.22       0.83
                         2011-05-03   2.94       0.25
                         2011-04-28   1.78       0.89
                         2011-04-22   1.35       0.92
...                                    ...        ...
5e33c514392b77d517961f06 2009-01-31  30.75       0.12
                         2009-01-24  30.50       0.21
                         2009-01-23  29.50       0.96
                         2009-01-10  28.50       0.98
                         2008-12-08  28.50       0.65
```

`when` is currently defined as an `index` but this is not a requirement.

#### Assertions

1. `when` may be non-unique.
2. Columns may be of unequal length across groups
3. Within groups `when`, `value` and `weight` will always be of equal length (for each `when` there will always be a `value` and a `weight`

#### Question

Using the parameter `index_time`, how do you retrieve:

1. The most recent past `value` and `weight` from each group relative to `index_time` along with the difference (in seconds) between `index_time` and `when`.
2. `index_time` may be a time in the past such that only entries where `when` <= `index_time` are selected.
3. The result should be indexed in some way so that the group id of each result can be deduced

#### Example

From the above, if the `index_time` was `2011-05-10` then the result should be:

```
                          value     weight      age                     
5e33c4bb4265514aab106a1a   1.22      0.83      259200
5e33c514392b77d517961f06  30.75      0.12    72576000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where original `DataFrame` given in the question is `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
result = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :when], :].groupby('id').tail(1)
result['age'] =  when - result.index.get_level_values(level=1)
```